# Short story- Slug-like alien eats his doctor

Tags: story-identification

I'm trying to track down a sci-fi short story my mom read ages ago. It must have been the late 70's or early 80's. I think it was in an anthology, but I could be mistaken.

A slug-like alien is arrested for murder, because the police (or whoever arrested it, I'm not sure), think it ate another alien. However, it turns out that the other alien is a doctor, and treats his/her/etc patients from the inside.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3):

I posted about this the other day, as a comment on another answer.

This is ["Resident Physician"](http://www.sectorgeneral.com/shortstories/residentphysician.html) by James White, one of the Sector General stories.

Answer (score 0):

Its from the Sector General series by James White.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sector_General

Comment: Can you clarify which book, which alien?

Comment: Sorry, it was a long time ago.